# PHP sockets - connection refused (unusual cause?)

Tags: php, connection-refused

I have a problem with a PHP script triggering a "connection refused" message. Im trying to execute file_get_contents('http://some_domain'). I have also tried fsockopen(), socket_create() and curl_exec() but they all result in "connection refused" on some specific sites that I want to reach. (i.e. its not a general problem).

- The resources *do* exist and I can contact them via my browser.
- If I run the PHP on my localhost server, it connects OK
- The problem is only apparent if I run the code on either of my remote servers
- The problem only occurs with *some* sites, not all sites
- The code worked OK until a few weeks ago

A common factor is that the three sites Im trying to reach are all running web servers behind domestic broadband routers that I installed (but with different broadband providers). But - as I said above - I can access them all from my browser, and the code worked until a few weeks ago. As far as I can see its not a firewall issue in the routers.

Im not sure what all that means - could there be some firewall issue on some intervening machine? How could I tell?

Comment: Can you access the sites through a browser on one of your remote hosts? Do the urls contain spaces or special characters? Can you curl (cli curl, not php) them on your remote machines? Are you sure the domestic IP address is still valid (how do you ensure)?

Comment: You haven't posted a single byte of code, so it's really hard to say at what point the error occurs. I can think of a variety of things that would prevent that command from working: php configured to NOT allow urls for file_get_contents function, socket extension not installed, curl extension not installed, firewall blocking the connection, insufficient credentials for remote machine, etc.

Comment: they might even have banned the IP ranges from where you perform the requests.

Comment: The PHP code "works" - I can access a "random URL"; e.g. **file_get_contents('http://google.co.uk')** will correctly return a string. The problem appears to be from _specific_ servers, accessing _specific_ URLs; and no, the URLs dont have special chars. Even just using a domain name, e.g. **file_get_contents('http://one-of-my-domains.com')** will _work_ if I run it from localhost, but _fails_ if I upload the code to one of my servers where (note) - I _can_ access other URLs.  It seems to be a firewall / IP blocking thing, but how to pin it down?

Comment: Since you claim to be the owner (one-of-my-domains.com), you should be able to check any firewall settings me thinks. You should then also be able to determine all other mentioned possibilities. I'm not sure how we can help you with that any further...

Comment: Well, it depends what you mean by owner. I pay for web space. I dont have full admin privileges on the server. Ive asked the sysadmin and he said he'll take a look but he's thinking the problem is upstream of him - where he has no control either. As I said: what is an "owner"? :-)

Comment: I afraid that's all you can do. From what I can read, there's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: I think I have pinned it down. Firstly, the behaviour is consistent across _all_ destinations, not selective ones, as I first thought. (I was confused because I dont use port 80 on my routers). Outgoing connections are being reset for all destinations on all ports _except_ ports 53 and 80. The problem appears to be that the company that provides the virtual server to the company that provides my web services may have installed a new firewall facility recently. I just need to find somebody there to talk to.

Comment: Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this turned out to be nothing but a *server* firewall problem. A new rule set had been loaded into iptables. Hopefully this will be useful to future enquirers - check iptables and your server log and save yourself a lot of time!